# Any major philosophy or ideology that promotes veganism?

Tags: veganism, outreach, philosophy

In a similar question it was asked which [major religions promote or require a vegetarian diet?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/98/115)

Here I'm asking for something quite different: not a religion but a philosophy or ideology. I'm thinking about perhaps some form of anarchism or deep ecology..

Additionally, unlike the previous question - that talks about religions that **require** veg*ism - here I ask for ideologies that **promote** it.

Any knowledge about that?

Comment: Non-anthropocentric utilitarianism, i.e Peter Singer comes to mind. But what exactly do you mean by 'promote, not require'?

Comment: Is this question about veganism, a strict vegetarian diet, or a lacto-ovo vegetarian diet?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you mean by "promote", but one can argue that **utilitarianism** is an ideology that justifies veganism/vegetarianism.

For example, it is [well established](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms11382) that being vegetarian reduces your footprint on arable land relative to an average Western diet (e.g., by reducing the demand for animal feed).  Since this indirectly slows the tearing down of rain forests, the rise in food prices, and the draining of water tables, one can argue that the overall marginal utility of being veg*n is higher than the marginal utility you would gain personally by eating animals.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are some [anarchist movements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism_and_animal_rights#Veganism_and_anarchism) with deep links with veganism and animal liberation.

The term veganarchism was popularized in 1995 thanks to the pamphlet [Animal Liberation and Social Revolution](https://theanarchistlibrary.org/library/brian-a-dominick-animal-liberation-and-social-revolution) of Brian A. Dominick which I think explains much better than I could the relation between the anarchist and vegan movements.

It is also very possible to find veg*n people in [Green Anarchist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_anarchism) circles and collectives.

P.S. I can expand the answer later if you want more info or references. Feel free to drop a comment if that is the case.

Comment: Good answer, upvoted. It would be good to have some references of other ideologies not into anarchism, if any.

Comment: @Attilio I'm not really familiar with other ideologies which promote a veg*n lifestyle but I will do some research and try to expand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Effective Altruism

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_altruism#Animal_welfare

There are three main cause priorities to this philosophy and movement. Animal rights is one of them.

*How to Create a Vegan World: A Pragmatic Approach* (2017) Leenaert has a forward by Peter Singer (one of the founders of Effective Altruism). Here is the [Google books preview](https://books.google.com/books?id=77UrDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).