# Besides animal suffering and caring for the environment, what common ethical reasons are there for veganism?

Tags: veganism, ethics

Many vegans follow this lifestyle "for ethical reasons". These reasons are usually related to **avoiding animal suffering and exploitation**. Moreover, some vegans might see the concern for the **environment** as a matter of ethics. Is there any other reason why people decide to go vegan?

**Clarification**: The question "[Reasons for being vegetarian or vegan other than ethical reasons?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/67/115)" addresses non-ethical reasons. Here I ask for *ethical reasons apart from "avoiding animal and environmental explotation"*, **if any**. If there are not other reasons, then the answer might simply be "there are not other reasons".

Comment: @Attilo, how is this question different to the related one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reasons for being vegetarian or vegan other than ethical reasons?](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/67/reasons-for-being-vegetarian-or-vegan-other-than-ethical-reasons)

Comment: @Steve It's the complete opposite, the previous question didn't address ethical reasons at all.

Comment: In the title you're asking for the _most common_ reasons. Then you're taking animal suffering and environmental reasons away. These are, after what I'd have guessed, the two biggest ethical reasons. Now, do you want to find _other_ ethical reasons? Consider editing the title then.

Comment: I've edited the title to more clearly reflect what the body says. If I misunderstood, feel free to edit it yourself. (but don't just roll back, something needs to be fixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with antibiotic resistance would be an ethical reason, even though it's mentioned in the other question.

One could also argue that there are ethical components to the health reasons:

1. You may be placing less strain on finances funded by taxes and insurance premiums.
2. You will cause loved ones less grief by dying later, and perhaps more peacefully.